How do I import Typescript types from this third-party library (ebay-api)?
I have the following typescript code:
import type { CoreItem } from 'ebay-api';

declare interface Props {
  item: CoreItem;
}

export default function Item({ item }: Props) {
  // <snip>
}

But when I try to build my next.js app I get this error:
./src/app/item.tsx:3:15
Type error: Module '"ebay-api"' has no exported member 'CoreItem'. Did you mean to use 'import CoreItem from "ebay-api"' instead?

How do I import the CoreItem type?

Why do you think that type exists as a Typescript type? Because I'm not seeing it...

Yes I saw it in src/types/restful/specs/buy_browse_v1_oas3.ts but I guess I didn't look closely enough to recognize that it's not a Typescript type

I see export interface components { ... CoreItem: { additionalImages?: (components["schemas"]["Image"])[]; ... }; So it looks like there is a components type but I still don't know how to import/reference it.

AFAICT you can't, this is the file that would export it but it doesn't. That type just isn't part of the public interface of the ebay api. You can see the file imports the components interface from that file as buyBrowse but then only exports certain schemas, and that doesn't appear to be one of them.

Thanks for taking a look. I'm going to define my own ebaySearchResultItem type and use that.

Good deal and good luck!

Developer responded here: https://github.com/hendt/ebay-api/issues/171#issuecomment-2137992820

The CoreItem is a type that is generated from OpenAPI.

import {components} from 'ebay-api/lib/types/restful/specs/buy_browse_v1_oas3.js';
type CoreItem = components['schemas']['CoreItem'];`

This worked!

I'm glad you got your problem solved, but understand that's a hack: they could change the name of that file and break you without a major version bump because that isn't exported by their package entry point. You're running a risk by reaching into the node_modules folder with an explicit path like that. It's your choice, just be aware of the fragility.

The alternative is to define the type myself, which is equally as likely to break right?

Correct, there isn't a great solution here.
